# Pass variables to route with URL::to in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Here is how I am calling it in a `create.blade.php` of the same controller as the route I am trying to call:

```
{{ Form::open(['route' => 'myRoute']) }}
   <button type="submit" href="{{ URL::to('myRoute') }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The Route is:

```
Route::post('myRoute', ['as' => 'timeline.myRoute', 'uses' => 'TimelineController@myRoute']);
```

I want to pass an integer to the the route. I know that ->with() doesn't work like in View::make(). What is an efficient way to pass a variable into `myRoute`? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeemusu was 90% correct but forgot to specify a variable when opening a form.

What ultimately ended up working was:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('timeline.myRoute', $id))) }}
      <button type="submit" href="{{ URL::route('timeline.myRoute', array($id))     }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini">Delete</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

With the Route in Route.php:

```
Route::post('myRoute/{id}', ['as' => 'timeline.myRoute', 'uses' => 'TimelineController@myRoute']);
```

And the function in my controller:

```
class TimelineController extends BaseController
{
     public function myRoute($id) {
          return $id;
     }
}
```

Hope this helps anyone who had my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) to pass data to your controller from the url.

Say you had a url like `http://yoursite.com/myRoute/id_number_here`. Your routes and controller might look like this.

**Route**

```
Route::post('myRoute/{id}', ['as' => 'timeline.myRoute', 'uses' => 'TimelineController@myRoute']);
```

**Controller**

```
public function myRoute($id) {
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: How should I be calling this in my button? I tried `href="{{ URL::route('timeline.deleteItem', array('id' => 1)) }}"` but the page just returns `{id}`

Comment: The URL to directs to is also `http://localhost:8000/myRoute/%7Bid%7D` which I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `URL::route('timeline.myRoute', array(1));` or even `URL::to('myRoute', array(1));`

Edit:

You route would be something like this:

```
Route::get('myRoute/{id}', ['as' => 'timeline.myRoute', 'uses' => 'TimelineController@myRoute']);
```

Then when you call to it with this:

```
echo URL::route('timeline.myRoute', array($id));
```

You can access in your controller:

```
class TimelineController extends BaseController
{
    public function myRoute($id) {
        echo $id;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how to I access the integer in `public function myRoute()`?

Comment: It redirects to http://localhost:8000/myRoute/%7Bid%7D with the error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException`